# Kubernetes blocking exec into pods?

Tags: kubernetes

For security purpose, I want to disable `exec` into pods, is there a kubernetes property that I can use, one why I thought was to disable user login on `OS` level.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh can you please elaborate

Comment: It's simple. You need to understand how rbac works, as explained at this link. Once you do use this knowledge to guide your changes. By default a person or application does not have _any_ access to you cluster unless you gave them that access, this of course includes `exec`. You control what access to give, so do accordingly.

Comment: That's the theory at least. On the other hand, if that did not work out for you, please do post the full details, about what you tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.